# "disqualify from" or "disqualify of" or "disqualify as"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

> If Jim do such a thing, then he is no more a trustworthy person.

I want to rephrase what is meant by the above sentence with the verb "disqualify".

Doing such a thing disqualifies Jim from being/of being/as a trustworthy person.

Which one is correct. Indeed, none of them is satisfactory as they look weird. So other suggestion for the verb "disqualify" are appreciated as well.

Comment: You're trying to use "disqualified" incorrectly.  Look it up again.

Comment: It's a matter of philosophy _when_ Jim 'stopped being trustworthy'. 'Doing such a thing proves that Jim is not trustworthy.'

Answer (score 2):

Let's fix basic grammar first. Your first sentence should read:

> If Jim **does** such a thing...

The construct "...he is no more a trustworthy person" is archaic (though acceptable). A modern writer would say

> "...he is no longer a trustworthy person."

Second, the word "disqualify" means to make ineligible. I doubt that you wish to communicate that Jim is no longer eligible to be a trustworthy person, but rather that he **is not** a trustworthy person. People are rarely thought of as being *eligible* to be trustworthy - they usually either are or are not.

The normal conjunction to use with 'disqualify' is 'from'. So a more usual use might be:

> Being guilty of a serious crime disqualifies Jim **from** being an election candidate.

'As' is also usable when talking about a role or position.

> Being a contributor to a political party disqualifies Jim as an election official.

Comment: Good answer.  Disqualify is also often used with "as", like "Lack of expertise disqualified Jim as a consultant."